# Rituals after death

Tags: rituals, karma, moksha, death, afterlife

Are the rituals like anta-yatra, agni sanskar, pindi- dan, tri-pindi shraddha and narayan nag bali mentioned specifically in pre manusmriti texts?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about the dating of texts, but yes Preta Kanda of Garuda Purana discusses elaborately the rituals one has to do after a person's demise. Here are a few lines  from Garuda Purana

> When it is ascertained that life has gone out of the body, the son
>   should bathe and wash the corpse with pure water without delay.
>
> The corpse should be laid lightly on earth with its head to the south.
>
> O bird, preta pinda is given inorder to comfort the deceased.
>
> The ten day period of asaucha has been prescribed for the relatives on
>   the father side.

Even other puranas like Padma Purana, Markandeya Purana etc talk about Sraddha ceremony.

The document that is recited usually at a person's death is [Garuda Purana Sarodhara](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/garuda-purana-saroddhara-GPA188/) is treated as equivalent to Garuda Purana. Garuda Purana full version is [here](https://ia600207.us.archive.org/19/items/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/Garuda%20Purana%20English%20-%20Motilal%20-%203%20Volumes%20in%201.pdf).

Hope this helps you.